# Exchange 2010 calendar synchronization problem

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sync, calendar, htc-sense, exchange

I've had my HTC Incredible S for a couple of weeks now, and have only just succeeded in synchronizing my Exchange 2010 calendar with it. E-mail and contacts have been working like a charm from the beginning.

I kept getting this useless error message:

> Synchronization is experiencing problems

I tried many things, including exporting my entire calendar to file, deleting all items in my calendar, and re-importing items, but to no avail. My collegues' calendars synced just fine to my phone. For some reason my calendar just wouldn't sync.

After a lot of messing around I found that if I made a change to **every single item** in my calendar, e.g. changing the subject of the item, and restoring it afterwards, I was able to sync the entire calendar. Finally!

A VBA macro helped me perform this absurd task in Outlook 2010:

```
Sub ChangeAllItems()
  Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim calendar As MAPIFolder
  Dim aItem As Object
  Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set calendar = myolApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
  Dim strTemp As String
  For Each aItem In calendar.Items
    strTemp = aItem.Subject
    'Make a change to the item (subject)
    aItem.Subject = strTemp & " "
    aItem.Save
    'Restore subject line
    aItem.Subject = strTemp
    aItem.Save
  Next aItem
End Sub
```

This question serves two purposes; first, to help others who are experiencing the same issue; second, to help me and others understand the reasons for this strange behaviour.

- Has anyone  had the same problem, but solved it differently?
- Does anyone know of a reasonable explanation to this behaviour?

I would make this community wiki, but can't find the setting.

Comment: The ability to make questions Community Wiki was removed some time ago. Mods can do it, but I don't think it's necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved my day. The only working solution to that recurring Exchange-Android Calendar sync problem that I found.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have currently the same problem, I found out that it is related to the import of a pst file.

The error occurs if a pst file is exported from an MS Exchange 2003 Server and afterwards imported on an Exchange 2010 Server. (e.g. in order to migrate from one version to another)
Everything works fine when using OWA or Outlook to access the data. The error you described shows up only on mobile devices so far. (In my case it is a Symbian phone with Dataviz roadsync on it)

Except editing all items, which makes them available again, I found no other solution so far. But I am curious to know if there is anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I suspected it had something to do with that!